# for loop pushing to many values into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

Note: Jquery or JS resolutions. I have an array called "Decimal" That receives 11 decimal values with the whole number removed (Ex: 0.25)

If I run these 7 if statements against a single value in my Decimal array like below, I get 1 value in the "Fraction" array, which is what I wanted to happen to confirm that the logic in the if() statements is correct.

```
        if (Decimal[1] <= 0.125) {Fraction.push('1/8');}
        if (Decimal[1] <= 0.25) {Fraction.push('1/4');}
        if (Decimal[1] <= 0.375) {Fraction.push('3/8');}
        if (Decimal[1] <= 0.50) {Fraction.push('1/2');}
        if (Decimal[1] <= 0.625) {Fraction.push('5/8');}
        if (Decimal[1] <= 0.75) {Fraction.push('3/4');}
        if (Decimal[1] <= 1) {Fraction.push('7/8');}
```

As soon as I put those 7 if statements into a for loop I get 44 values in the Fraction Array ( I was expecting 11). See Code Below:

```
for (var t = 0; t < Decimal.length; t++) {
        if (Decimal[t] <= 0.125) {Fraction.push('1/8');}
        if (Decimal[t] <= 0.25) {Fraction.push('1/4');}
        if (Decimal[t] <= 0.375) {Fraction.push('3/8');}
        if (Decimal[t] <= 0.50) {Fraction.push('1/2');}
        if (Decimal[t] <= 0.625) {Fraction.push('5/8');}
        if (Decimal[t] <= 0.75) {Fraction.push('3/4');}
        if (Decimal[t] <= 1) {Fraction.push('7/8');}
    }
```

Comment: If a number is less than or equal to `0.125`, then it's also less than or equal to `1`, right?

Comment: use `if .... else if ..`

Comment: if you have .003 its less than all those numbers so they will get pushed ?

Comment: Not if the number is a decimal, like 0.1... I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at.

Comment: @dm8021122: `0.1` is less than `0.125`, so you push `1/8`, but `0.1` is also less than `0.25`, so you also push `1/4` and so on. Anything less than `0.125` will push all `7` values. I imagine that isn't what you wanted. As others have said, use `else if`.

Comment: When you have a decimal number of `.100` what are you expecting to be pushed into the array?  Because right now, you're going to push all 7 of those values into the array... since .100 < .125, and it's < .25, and it's < .375, etc.

Comment: Also, your question would be better if you included which value you are using for `Decimal`. What's `Decimal[1]` for example? I'm guessing it's `> 0.75`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need else if statements for all but the first condition otherwise one value could match more than one statement:

```
for (var t = 0; t < Decimal.length; t++) {
  if (Decimal[t] <= 0.125) {Fraction.push('1/8');}
  else if (Decimal[t] <= 0.25) {Fraction.push('1/4');}
  else if (Decimal[t] <= 0.375) {Fraction.push('3/8');}
  else if (Decimal[t] <= 0.50) {Fraction.push('1/2');}
  else if (Decimal[t] <= 0.625) {Fraction.push('5/8');
  else if (Decimal[t] <= 0.75) {Fraction.push('3/4');}
  else if (Decimal[t] <= 1) {Fraction.push('7/8');}
}
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as my answer?  What value is there having two answers which are the same?

Comment: @Hogan sorry when I posted your answer wasn't there - was on a train with dodgy internet must have only uploaded later xD

Answer (score 0):

not sure what test you did but this is the logic you need:

```
for (var t = 0; t < Decimal.length; t++) {
    if (Decimal[t] <= 0.125) {Fraction.push('1/8');}
    else
    if (Decimal[t] <= 0.25) {Fraction.push('1/4');}
    else
    if (Decimal[t] <= 0.375) {Fraction.push('3/8');}
    else
    if (Decimal[t] <= 0.50) {Fraction.push('1/2');}
    else
    if (Decimal[t] <= 0.625) {Fraction.push('5/8');}
    else
    if (Decimal[t] <= 0.75) {Fraction.push('3/4');}
    else
    if (Decimal[t] <= 1) {Fraction.push('7/8');}
}
```

note:  it is better to use `{}` in the else area but I was to lazy to type all those.

Comment: Thank you that helps fix the problem. I am a bit confused by the difference between what I've got and what you put down though. Other than to say that technically I wrote 7 if statements and you wrote 1 long if else statement. Is that what was causing my problem?

Comment: @dm8021122 - That is one way to look at it.  Your logic checked the value 7 times and some values were true multiple times.  My logic checks only the number of times needed to find a true value and then stops checking.  This is how I think about it.  There are other ways to solve this problem using my same logic -- for example you use an switch statement.